# Using the Strong Markov property to show that a Brownian motion depending on a stopping time is identically distributed with a shifted BM

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, markov-process

This is a claim I found from Rene Schilling's Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus, but I don't know how to prove it.

Let $\tau= \tau(B_\bullet)$ be a stopping time which can be expressed as a functional of a Brownian path, e.g. a first hitting time, and assume that $\sigma$ is a further stopping time such that $\sigma \le \tau $ a.s. Denote by $\tau' = \tau(B_{\bullet + \sigma})$ the stopping time $\tau$ for the shifted process $B_{\bullet+ \sigma}$, which is the remaining time, counting from $\sigma$, until the event described by $\tau $ happens.

Set $W_\bullet:= B_{\bullet + \sigma} - B_\sigma$; then $\tau' = \tau(W_\bullet+ B_\sigma),$ and the functionals $u(B_\tau)$ and $u(W_{\tau'} + B_\sigma)$ have the same distribution, where $u : \mathbf{C}[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded $\mathcal{B}(\mathbf{C})/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable functional.

The only property I have are the strong Markov properties in the following forms: $\bullet \;W_t:= B_{\sigma +t} - B_\sigma$, is again a Brownian motion which is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma +}$ for an a.s. finite stopping time $\sigma$.

$\bullet \;$ Let $\sigma$ be a stopping time. For all bounded Borel measurable $u \in \mathscr{B}_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $P$ almost all $\omega \in \{\sigma < \infty\}$
$$E[u(B_{t+\sigma})|\mathscr{F}_{\sigma+}](\omega)=E[u(B_t+x)]|_{x = B_\sigma(\omega)}=E^{B_\sigma(\omega)}u(B_t).$$

$\bullet$ For all bounded $\mathscr{B}(C)/\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable functionals $\Psi : C[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ which may depend on a whole Brownian path and $P$ almost all $\omega \in \{\sigma < \infty\}$ this becomes
$$E[\Psi(B_{\bullet + \sigma})|\mathscr{F}_{\sigma +}]=E[\Psi(B_\bullet +x)]|_{x=B_\sigma}=E^{B_\sigma}[\Psi(B_\bullet)].$$

How can I use these properties to show that $u(B_\tau)$ and $u(W_{\tau'} + B_\sigma)$ have the same distribution (conditional on $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma +}$ is I think what the author means)? I have been stuck with this for some time and would greatly appreciate some help. Moreover, how do these facts imply the corollary that
$$E[u(B_{\tau}) | \mathscr{F}_{\sigma +}](\omega)=E[u(W_{\tau'}+x)]|_{x=B_\sigma (\omega)}=E^{B_{\sigma}(\omega)} u(W_{\tau'})$$ holds for all $u\in \mathscr{B}_b(\mathbb{R}^d$) and P almost all $\omega \in \{\tau<\infty\}.$

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood something, but don't you have $\tau=\sigma+\tau'$ a.s.?

Comment: @jakobdt I agree but can't think of a rigorous argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only found the book R.L. Schilling, L. Partzsch *Brownian Motion* which has the claim that $u(B_\tau)$ and $u(W_{\tau'}+B_\sigma)$ have the same distribution at the bottom of p.  63. They don't say that $u$ is defined on $\mathbf{C}[0,+\infty)$. It is obviously rather a measurable function on $\mathbb R^d\,.$

***Claim.*** *The functionals $u(B_\tau)$ and $u(W_{\tau'}+B_\sigma)$ do not only have the same
distribution, they are almost surely equal.*

*Proof.*
By definition of $W_\bullet$ we have $W_{\tau'}+B_\sigma=B_{\tau'+\sigma}\,.$ By definition of $\tau'$ we have,
as jacobdt already pointed out, $\tau=\tau'+\sigma\,\,$ a.s. and therefore
$B_\tau=B_{\tau'+\sigma}=W_{\tau'}+B_\sigma\,\,$ a.s. and in particular $u(B_\tau)=u(W_{\tau'}+B_\sigma)\,\,$ a.s.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$

***Edit.***

- In their Corollary 6.7 the authors formulate more clearly that
  $\tau=\tau(B_\bullet)$ should be a ***first hitting time*** and $\sigma$ a stopping time with $\sigma\le\tau\,\,$ a.s. This makes the crucial relationship
  $$\tag{1}
  \tau'=\tau-\sigma\quad\text{ a.s. }
  $$
  straightforward to show. See below.
- On p. 63 Schilling and Partzsch only wrote that $\tau=\tau(B_\bullet)$ needs to be a functional of the Brownian path, ***e.g.*** *a first hitting time*. I think this is not enough but they don't need that full generality for the Corollary as stated.

***Proof of (1).***

Since $\tau=\tau(B_\bullet)$ is a first hitting time there is a Borel set $A$ in $\mathbb R^d$ s.t.
$$\tag{2}
\tau=\inf\{t>0:B_t\in A\}\,.
$$
Since $\sigma\le\tau\,\,$ a.s. it follows that
$$\tag{3}
B_\sigma\notin A\quad\text{ a.s. on }\quad\{\sigma<\tau\}\,.
$$ By definition, $\tau'=\tau(B_{\bullet+\sigma})\,,$ i.e.,
$$\tag{4}
\tau'=\inf\{t>0:B_{t+\sigma}\in A\}\,.
$$
By a variable transformation this can clearly be written as
$$\tag{5}
\tau'=\underbrace{\inf\{t'>\sigma:B_{t'}\in A\}}_{\textstyle=:\,\tau^*}-\sigma\,.
$$
It is clear that $\tau^*\ge\tau$ a.s. because the infimum in $\tau^*$ is taken over a smaller range of $t'$ values. However, from (3) it follows that
$$\tag{6}
B_t\notin A\quad\text{ a.s. on }\quad\{t\le \sigma<\tau\}\,.
$$
This means that in the definition (2) of $\tau$ we are allowed to take
the range of $t$ values over the smaller $t>\sigma$ as well, at least for almost all
$\omega$ in $\{\sigma<\tau\}\,.$ In other words,
$$\tag{7}
\tau^*=\tau\quad\text{ a.s. on }\quad\{\sigma<\tau\}\,.
$$
On $\{\sigma=\tau\}$ it follows from (4) that $\tau'=0\,.$ This finishes the proof of (1).
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$

Comment: Can you explain why $\tau = \tau' +  \sigma $ ? Consider for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the constant stopping times $ n = \tau \geq \sigma = n$. Then isn't $\tau' = \tau = n$?

Comment: Good point. See edit.

Comment: @KurtG. You're using a different edition to mine but they are essentially the same. I've been thinking of a rigorous way to show the obvious identity $\tau=\tau' + \sigma$. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @KurtG. I don't think they are almost surely equal I feel that the author would have stated otherwise if so.  The proof may involve the shift operator but I have no more clue at the moment.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician  If they are not a.s. equal what are they in your opinion? Please find the flaw -if any- in my line of reasoning. The fact that some prefer a shift operator should be irrelevant.  And BTW, who are "they" exactly? The stopping times or the "functionals"?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician As I pointed out in a previous comment, it is indeed not true in general that $\tau = \tau' + \sigma$. However this should hold for the special case of first hitting times. Can you show this?

Comment: @AdityaDhawan Did I not show just that? Why do you want OP to show it again?

Comment: Apologies, I did not see your latest edit.